# skeleton of empty javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I created a skeleton of a javascript function with prototype:

```
'use strict';  
var functionName = (function () {  
    var functionName = function(param1){  
        console.log("functionName " + param1);  
        this.init(param1);  
    };  

    // public function  
    functionName.prototype = {  
        init : function(param1) {  
            console.log("init " + param1);  
            var privateVar = param1;  
            this.setFunction();  
        },  
        setFunction : function() {  
            console.log("setFunction");  
            // do stuff here  

        }  
    };  

    return functionName;  
}());  

// Instances creation  
var f1 = new functionName("f1");  
var f2 = new functionName("f2");  
f1.setFunction();  
console.log("private var : " + f1.privateVar);
```

See the code in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/hPw6C/)
What do you think?
Here is the log of this script:

```
functionName f1 (index):25  
init f1 (index):32  
setFunction (index):37  
functionName f2 (index):25  
init f2 (index):32  
setFunction (index):37  
setFunction (index):37  
private var : undefined (index):51
```

I don't understand why I saw three times `setFunction`. Does someone have an idea?
The prototype of the function `SetFunction` should not be executed once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking `this.setFunction();` within your initial `init`. This is being hit whenever you invoke your constructor.

Therefore, it gets hit twice with both:

```
var f1 = new functionName("f1");  
var f2 = new functionName("f2");
```

Then you are separately calling it again, to get the third time:

```
f1.setFunction();
```